# Maximum Sum Subarray using Divide & Conquer, why use for loop a different way, the answer is wrong?

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int MaximumSum(int A[], int low, int high)
{
    if (high == low)
        return A[low];

    int mid = (low + high) / 2;

    int leftMax = INT_MIN;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = mid; i >= low; i--) 
    {
        sum += A[i];
        if (sum > leftMax)
            leftMax = sum;
    }

    /*
    why not write this way? I know when coding like this, answer is wrong.
    for (int i = low; i <= mid; i++)
    {
        sum += A[i];
        if (sum > leftMax)
            leftMax = sum;
    }
    */

    int rightMax = INT_MIN;
    sum = 0;    // reset sum to 0
    for (int i = mid + 1; i <= high; i++) 
    {
        sum += A[i];
        if (sum > rightMax)
            rightMax = sum;
    }

    int maxLeftRight = max(MaximumSum(A, low, mid), 
            MaximumSum(A, mid + 1, high));

    return max(maxLeftRight, leftMax + rightMax);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { -2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    cout << "The Maximum sum of the subarray is " << 
            MaximumSum(arr, 0, n - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

**my question is when solve leftMax, why not use for loop from low to mid,what's the difference between right version and wrong version, I know for loop in sequence is wrong, but I wonder why?I don't know why I can't submit...**

Answer (score 0):

You want to compute sub-array for middle point, so for the left part, you have to compute from right to left.
For example for

```
[5, -42, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

parts are

```
[5, -42, 2, 0] [1, 2, 3]
```

computing from left to right for `[5, -42, 2, 0]` gives `5`
whereas computing from left to right gives `2`

so the sub-array sum containing 0 (`mid`) is

```
[2, 0] + [1, 2, 3]
```

BTW, your algorithm is not optimal, it could be done in linear complexity.

Comment: thanks, I kown divide and conquer algorithm time complexity is O(nlogn),Kadane algorithm is the best solution.btw,are you familiar with machine learning?I know this topic is beyond the scope of the discussion,do you think by taking machine learning classes on coursera can help ordinary programmer get into machine learning field?Actually, I am a python rookie programmer from China, my job basiclly is fetching some data from internet, sometimes I wrote some web code, I think it's pretty boring,  machine learning has became a big trend in my country.In the meantime,  ml needs programmer know more